# How to pass a PHP id to create two bootstrap button diffrent id's and use its for jquery functin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<?php
    include_once('config.php');
    $sql="SELECT * FROM events";                                                         
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(!$result)
    {
     echo "no record found";
    }
    else
    {                                                                   
        while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
         $e_id=$row['e_id'];         
    ?>
                    <?php 
                        $_SESSION['r']=$e_id."rr";
                        $_SESSION['l']=$e_id."ll";
                    ?>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" id="<?php echo $_SESSION['r']; ?>" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo  $e_id; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<?php echo  $e_id; ?>">View More &raquo;</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" id="<?php echo  $_SESSION['l']; ?>" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo  $e_id; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<?php echo  $e_id; ?>">View Less &laquo;</a></br>
                </p>



                 <script>
                 var l = "<?php echo $_SESSION['l'];?>";
                 var r = "<?php echo $_SESSION['r'];?>";
                 alert(r);
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                      $("#"+r).show();
                      $("#"+l).hide();

                      $("#"+l).click(function(){
                        $("#"+l).hide();
                        $("#"+r).show();
                      });

                      $("#"+r).click(function(){
                        $("#"+r).hide();
                        $("#"+l).show();
                      });
                     });
                 </script>


<?php        
        }//while

    }//else 
 ?>
```

I fetch data $e_id from database then use it to create two buttons with added char to differ rr and ll as their id's then store in session. Now how to use it in jquery to show/hide each one. data-toggle on button is different div works fine. If i alert(r) gives 1rr 2rr 3rr, and alert(l) 1ll 2ll 3ll. I have 1,2,3 as id in database how can i use this button id's in script. session_start() was on top of page. The problem is hide/show not working guess I'm doing wrong. How can I call that id's properly?

Comment: How about indenting the code...

Comment: I hope its okey now, i'm still not get used to formatting I'm a newbie thanks for feedback anyway.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @MehulMohan i think I'm calling id's wrong hide/show not working i don't know how to go around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. The script is outside the loop. I can also add in a non jquery version in a bit as well if you want.

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM events";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(!$result)
    exit('no record found');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-default button-right" id="e-left-<?=$row['e_id']; ?>" data-id="<?=$row['e_id']; ?>" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?=$row['e_id']; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<?=$row['e_id']; ?>">View More &raquo;</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default button-left" id="e-right-<?=$row['e_id']; ?>" data-id="<?=$row['e_id']; ?>" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?=$row['e_id']; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<?=$row['e_id']; ?>">View Less &laquo;</a></br>
    </p>
<?php } ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.button-right').each(function() { 

            $(this).show(); 

            $(this).click(function() {
                $(this).hide();
                $('#e-left-'+this.dataset.id).show();
            }); 
        });

        $('.button-left').each(function() {

            $(this).hide();

            $(this).click(function() {
                $(this).hide();
                $('#e-right-'+this.dataset.id).show();
            }); 
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: i use your first answer it works perfectly i just add $(".a_left_button").show(); $(".a_right_button").hide(); for the default look and remove session. i just use session to manipulate id as left and right but this id="left_button_<?php echo $e_id; ?>" from your first answer is perfect. I prefer your first answer its not to confusing for me. Upvoted.

Comment: lol np, glad to be of service. There wasn't any upvote though. Heh.

Comment: oh yeah to low reputation for me to count in